# Why is the theoretical mode of exponential distribution different than numerically simulated one

Tags: r, distributions, exponential-distribution

I calculated the theoretical mode for X ~ Expo(lambda) and got it as 0. However, when I simulated the scenario in R, I am getting some values. My code is shown below:

```
sample_mode <- function(x) {
  t <- table(x)
  m <- max(t)
  as.numeric(names(t[t==m]))
}
simfunc <-function(){
  x <- rexp(10000,2)
  median <- median(x)
  mode <- sample_mode(x)

  cat("The median is", median)
  cat("The mode is", mode)
}
```

The median matches, but I am getting a vector of values for the mode.

Comment: Why don't you look at the data?  A quick graph, such as a histogram, ought to answer your question immediately.

Comment: I had a look at the histogram and it makes sense, but it my theoretical mode wrongly calculated then?

Comment: It's the way you're calculating the mode in your sample that's the problem. For some similar points to the ones in Tim's answer, also see the discussion of sample mode [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157661/how-to-calculate-mean-median-mode-std-dev-from-distribution/157669#157669) (though the mention of smoothing won't be much use when the mode is at the boundary, unless the smoothing also takes account of that)

Answer (score 4):

Exponential distribution is a distribution for a continuous random variable. For continuous random variables [$\Pr(X=x)=0$ for *any* $x$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142730/px-x-0-when-x-is-continuous-variable), so for your variable you would expect each of the distinct values not more then once in your sample, so your function for calculating mode would not produce any reasonable result. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19952/computing-the-mode-of-data-sampled-from-a-continuous-distribution) you can find some hints how you could calculate mode for continuous variable.